# How to Make Alphabet ListView like contacts But Horizontal

Tags: android, view, android-listview

In this [link](http://codelikes.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-alphabet-listview-like-contacts.html?zx=6f71d550da04e4be) they are showing alphabet list-view vertically. My need is same as it But the Alphabet List View Should be Horizontal.
I mean Alphabet Should Show Like this.

A B C D E ...........Z

Not like this

A

B

C

.

.

.

.

Z

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to horizontal list view [Link](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView) 
and use compare method for compare arraylist alphbaticaly

```
@Override
    public int compare(JBSelectedUrls object1, JBSelectedUrls object2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return object1.getStrSelectedWebsiteName().compareTo(
                object2.getStrSelectedWebsiteName());
    }
```